# what happens in python when using word in

Tags: python-3.x

what happens when I execute this code with word `in` (assume I created class A), more specifically how objects are compared:

```
my_list = [A(1), A(2), A(3)]
A(1) in my_list  # returns True
A(-3) in my_list  # returns False
```

I am interested in technical details of what is going on (if `hash` or `repr` method is called etc.) so I would be very interested in expert level answer to this question

Comment: It's easy to find [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-operations) though.

Comment: Please RTM [about comparison operators](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__lt__).

Answer (score 1):

The expression `x in y` can be thought of as doing:

```
any(x is e or x == e for e in y)
```

Note that it may be the case that `A(12) != A(12)`, if you have not defined equality for the class `A`.

Comment: "equivalent" might be a strong word when used generally. If `y` is a list maybe, but not if it's a set.

Comment: well my answer is very shallow and I would be very interested in expert level answers (@Carcigenicate sure for `set` method `hash` is called)